# Prosperity in Judaism

Tags: money

Is there a duality notion of prosperity in Judaism? I say this because there are texts that suggest that prosperity or well-being leads to destruction, as in Proverbs 1:32. If the impression of well-being leads to perdition and being in perdition there is the promise that if you convert things will improve, does this not lead to a vicious cycle? Is there kosher prosperity? I say this because in many biblical stories the nation's quest for prosperity involved trade with idolatrous nations allowing free movement within the country to attract merchants. Is it possible to get away from it all and succeed? Solomon prospered greatly by making alliances with neighboring nations, which did not end well for him and his kingdom. So what would be the solution? Nowadays, the view we have is that Jews are very rich and at the same time it is said that the majority are secular Jews, implying that this correlation of prosperity and purity seems to be something difficult to achieve. What do you think?

Comment: There's no duality. Prosperity is in and of itself neutral, or perhaps good (wealth is important for dignity, health, calm, charity, freedom to pursue Torah...). The issue is that it is dangerous as it leads to complacency and haughtiness, and is so dangerous that many nations have failed to grow through prosperity, and have in fact succumbed to sin. BTW the vast majority of Jews are not "rich", except a few hyper successful ones but I'm not sure we can draw any Torah lessons from this.

Comment: Let's say that's the case. Is there any example of someone very prosperous and getting through unscathed? Or is prosperity more than financial assets? Or something that provides a lot of power in the hands that can lead to some arbitrariness?

Comment: Many of the Sages of the Talmud were immensely wealthy. Rabbi Yehuda Hanasi was, for example, and he is listed as the only person who never once derived physical pleasure from the world.

Comment: There's something I forgot to put in the question but I'll do it right here. Does prosperity come exclusively from God? Why is it said that we should not envy the prosperity of the wicked? Can God prosper a person aiming at a punishment?

Comment: Yes Judaism 101, everything comes from God, prosperity is no exception. Prosperity is neutral so isn't necessarily a reward, but can be considered one, especially for a wicked person who has a few good deeds that need just reward. Prosperity isn't considered a very good reward in Torah :)

Comment: @RabbiKaii - I'm not sure I completely agree. Every yid has his "pekel", there are plenty of very affluent Jews. Ultimately, it all comes from G-d. One can argue that those that benefit in olam hazeh possibly lose out in olam habah, but everyone is granted with varying level of bracha. Pirkei Avos perhaps puts it best when it says - "אֵיזֶהוּ עָשִׁיר, הַשָּׂמֵחַ בְּחֶלְקוֹ" - "Who is wealthy? One who is happy with his lot".

Comment: @Dov what exactly are you countering as I didn't catch that? Prosperity is indeed considered bracha in many contexts, but less so in terms of schar/pras. The quote in Avot is actually redefining prosperity away from money and more towards a state of mind

Comment: I don't think prosperity is necessarily neutral. Sometimes Hashem blesses people with wealth so that they can give huge amounts to tzedaka.

Comment: @Dov that's what I wrote in the first comment

Comment: A helpful note that hasn't been mentioned, Psalm 73. Sometimes the wicked prosper, therefore it is not always a sign of blessing. Pharaoh was rich and powerful-- and Hashem raised him up to his high position so that Hashem's power could be displayed in Pharaoh's destruction, and Hashem's name proclaimed in all the earth (Exodus 9:16). As for the righteous, their pursuit is to have no desire on earth but Hashem alone (73:25). He is enough for us (73:26), with or without prosperity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for this great question there is lots to say on it.

### **1) Wealth is a G-d-given gift**

As a starting point, one needs to acknowledge that wealth and prosperity is something that comes direct from G-d.

Shlomo HaMelech writes in [Koheles 5:18](https://www.sefaria.org/Ecclesiastes.5.18?lang=bi):

> Also, whenever a man is given riches and property by God, and is also permitted by Him to enjoy them and to take his portion and get pleasure for his gains—that is a gift of God.

However, as with anything that G-d bestows upon a person, there is a responsibility to use it correctly.

[Pirkei Avos 2:4](https://www.sefaria.org/Pirkei_Avot.2.4?ven=The_Mishna_with_Obadiah_Bartenura_by_Rabbi_Shraga_Silverstein&lang=bi) exhorts us to

> Make His will like your will, so that He make your will like His will [i.e., so that He grant you good with an open hand.]

[Bartenura](https://www.sefaria.org/Bartenura_on_Pirkei_Avot.2.4.1?lang=bi) explains on this:

> "Make His [God's] will like your will": Spread your money on 'things of Heaven' "like your will," [meaning] as if you were spreading them for your [own] things. As if you will do this, "He will make His will like your will," meaning to say that He will give you the good with 'a generous eye.'

Wealth brings the opportunity to give charity. This gifts us the ability to show our gratitude to G-d for the wealth we have received. By showing Hashem that we value his blessing and are prepared to use it in a positive way it can only bring renewed blessing.

[Pirkei Avos 2:7](https://www.sefaria.org/Pirkei_Avot.2.7?lang=bi) notes:

> מַרְבֶּה צְדָקָה, מַרְבֶּה שָׁלוֹם - The more charity, the more peace

**Thus, wealth is seen as a good thing when channelled in the correct way and does not need to mean that its result is one of perdition or suffering.**

### **2) Keeping G-d in the picture**

Once we appreciate that wealth comes direct from G-d, we have to acknowledge that not everyone is blessed with it. [Gemara Berachos 5b](https://www.sefaria.org/Berakhot.5b.14?ven=William_Davidson_Edition_-_English&lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) relates, "לֹא כׇּל אָדָם זוֹכֶה לִשְׁתֵּי שֻׁלְחָנוֹת" - not everyone merits to eat off two tables i.e. enjoy successes in Torah AND wealth.

As such, we have to learn to appreciate what we have - (See [Pirkei Avos 4:1](https://www.sefaria.org/Pirkei_Avot.4.1?vhe=Torat_Emet_357&lang=bi) - "Who is wealthy? someone is happy with his lot."). As Jews we aspire to live a more loftier lifestyle, embracing a life that is first and foremost, one of ruchniyus - spirituality. This is seen as a higher goal. We engage in Torah and mitzvos.

This should be the central focus. [Pirkei Avos 4:9](https://www.sefaria.org/Pirkei_Avot.4.9?vhe=Torat_Emet_357&lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) notes:

> Rabbi Yonasan said: whoever fulfills the Torah out of a state of poverty, his end will be to fulfill it out of a state of wealth; And whoever discards The Torah out of a state of wealth, his end will be to discard it out of a state of poverty.

Thus, first comes Torah, which if we duly apply ourselves then G-d will bring us reward. The problem many people have, is the moment they see success in this area, they can fall into the mindset that it is כוחי ועוצם ידי - it all comes from my own success, my own business acumen, leaving G-d out of the picture.

### **3) The Dangers**

You mention that;

> prosperity or well-being leads to destruction

Building on what we have said, G-d both gives and takes. If He feels we are not utilising this wealth in the right way then He will strip it from us.

In Chovos Halevavos it writes expressly:

> If he relies on his wealth, it will be removed from him and left to someone else as written "He lies down rich, but there shall be nothing to gather; he opens his eyes, and his wealth is not" ([Iyov 27:19](https://www.sefaria.org/Job.27.19?lang=bi)), "Do not weary yourself to grow rich; cease from your own understanding." ([Mishlei 23:4](https://www.sefaria.org/Proverbs.23.4?lang=bi)), "Should you blink your eyes at it, it is not here; for it will make wings for itself, like the eagle, and it will fly toward the heavens." ([Mishlei 23:5](https://www.sefaria.org/Proverbs.23.5?lang=bi)), "so it is he who gathers riches but not by right; he shall leave them in the midst of his days, and at his end he stands dishonored" ([Yirmiyahu 17:11](https://www.sefaria.org/Jeremiah.17.11?lang=bi))

### **4) Conclusion**

So wealth is something that comes direct from Hashem. It is to be seen as a blessing and does not have to come through suffering. Rather we have a responsibility to honour G-d's name with it through giving charity etc. and if we do not utilise it in the correct way then G-d can take it just as easily as He first gave it.